# ARM template: How to reference a resource that has its name set using a parameter

Tags: azure, parameters, reference, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure Resource Manager template to spin up a storage account, and its name is being set using a parameter, like this:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
```

I want to output details of the resource, but can't see a way of referencing the storage account, as most examples I can find reference the resource by name.

I've tried this:

```
    "outputs": {
    "storageKey": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference([parameters('storageAccountName')])]"
    }
}
```

But get the error message:

> The template output 'storageKey' at line '49' and column '23' is not valid: 
>   Unable to parse language expression 'reference([parameters('storageAccountName')])': expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket'

So how do I reference the resource if its name is set using a parameters.json file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just to add to existing answer (which is fine, but incomplete). a better way of doing this is using the `resourceId()` function:

```
reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), 'api-version-goes-here')
```

there are several reason for that.

1. this is a universal way of referencing a resource. you can reference a resource in another resource group\another subscription using this method (and not only resources in the same deployment). you can drop 'api-version-goes-here' for resources in the same deployment
2. the existing answer will fail if you have 2 or more resources of different type but having the same name (say storage account and virtual machine), because it wont be able to determine which resource you are targeting

ps. same goes for `dependsOn`, you can get away with just the name, but I find its always better\more reliable to use `resourceId()`, especially in big\complicated templates.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's really useful. So resourceId is essentially a lookup of the resource Id? I.e. lookup(type of thing to be looked up, name of thing to be looked up)

Comment: not even looking up, its just constructing it, since its well known given resourceType\resourceName. reference() would be looking it up

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The internal square brackets were unnecessary:

```
        "storageKey": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
    }
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

Use of resourceId() is recommended.

Check MS documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

It returns the unique identifier of a resource. You use this function when the resource name is ambiguous or not provisioned within the same template.